# GeoPoint in Java not mapping geo_point when I use annotation on class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

First I use the following version in Springboot project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My class is like this:

```
//@GeoPointField
private GeoPoint location;
//@Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
private String userId;
```

When I use Annotation, the es mapping location is like this:

```
"location": {
  "properties": {
    "lon": {
     "type": "double"
    },
    "lat": {
     "type": "double"
   }
  }
}
```

What I want is : location'type is geo_point.

Of course when I remove All the annotation except @Id , it did.

But I want the annotation to do some features, please give some ideas.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm also having problems getting the `geo_point` data type.